# How to use JQuery Custom Validators and onChange Event in <input type='file' /> using ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

### Invoking custom jquery validator within another javascript function

How to invoke jQuery Custom Validator for a `<input type='file' />` on onChange Event  within normal javascript function. I need to capture the event and trigger a custom validator already registered, inside it creates a table with rows corresponding to each file attempted to upload.
I have read this article but I can't validate what the author is saying: [Version of Custom Validator Calling](http://devblog.springest.com/calling-built-in-validation-methods-from-the-jquery-validation-plugin-inside-custom-validation-methods)

Thanks in advance.

---

I have a piece of jquery custom validator function that makes the magic, it checks valid files extensions (images are the main target right now) when uploading them to the server:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#UploadedFile').live('change', function () {
    //TODO
    alert('Hey hey!');//It works, because the event is captured and calls this line
    return jQuery.validator.methods.extensions.call(null, $(this), null);//Doesn't work for me
 
   //This is for running validation in the client-side      
});
```

});

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("extensions", function (value, element, params) {
var extensionsAllowed = params.extensions;
var pattern = new RegExp(extensionsAllowed);
var elementToValidate = $(element);
var maxUploadSize = Math.floor(5000000 / 1024) / 1024;//converting to Kilobytes

var result = fnCreateUploadDetailsTable(elementToValidate, pattern, maxUploadSize);
return result;

   //It works for server-side Data Annotations validator, 
   //but the request travels over the HTTP connection and I want to avoid overloading the server
   //with this basic function
});

jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("extensions", ["extensions"], function (options) {
options.rules["extensions"] = options.params;
options.messages["extensions"] = options.message;
});
```

Comment: It's very unclear why you are doing this.  The jQuery Validate plugin already checks each field on various events by default... `onfocusout`, `onkeyup`, `onclick`, `onsubmit`, etc.  Also, using the `additional-methods.js` file, you can assign the rule for file extensions... no need to create a new one.  http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/CustomMethods/extension#extension

Comment: I need it because I created a custom file extensions validator and it worked requesting to the server-side and I'm pushing myself to achieve this from the client-side. Because with onChange I would show a container with files metadata loaded in the browser, previous to sending the files. And the only parameters I check are: type and size. Nothing more. I appreciate further assistance.

Comment: If the file is already on the server-side, then "client-side" validation is not what you need.  Again, I'm requesting that you edit your OP to explain more about what you're trying to achieve and where it's failing.

Comment: The files aren't submitted with server validation, always remain in the browser cache. That is what I intend to handle. Using those files metadata and print a table with problematic files. I put some comments explaining it. What do you need specifically, besides comments in code? Would you know a syntax for inline-calling jquery validators? Thanks.

Comment: This will be my last response.  What I would like to see is that you _edit your OP_ to better explain what you're trying to achieve and exactly where it's failing.  Simply saying, _"I have read this article but I can't validate what the author is saying"_ is not an adequate problem description.    I wish you the best of luck in solving your problem.